# Is there a QGIS plugin that reclassify raster symbology based on current extent?

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, symbology, plugins

I am working with an elevation raster. I have assigned it color ramp symbology based on elevation. It looks like as the image shown below currently when zoomed to the layer.

[image: Raster Symbology QGIS, Zoomed to the Layer]

But when I zoom in to start working on the map, the symbology is still the same; hence the color difference is not stark enough to differentiate between low points and high points.

My question is that; is there a plugin which can, with the help of one button press, reset my symbology based on my current extent so that the highest point in that area and the lowest point have entirely different colors.

In ArcMap, one can do that easily with the reset legend elevation option for TINs and Terrains as shown in the second picture below.

[image: ArcMap TIN Legend Reset to the Current Extent]

I am looking for something similar in QGIS for rasters. If there is no plugin already, can this kind of plugin be created using Python ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes there is, in QGIS 3 at least (I'm on QGIS 3.4, but I think this came in 3.2? Or maybe earlier)

In the raster symbology, change statistics min/max settings to  "Updated canvas" and make sure accuracy is "actual (slower)"

[image]

As you zoom in and pan around, the colour ramp will be clamped to the min/max values of the current extent.

Comment: Thanks Steven,
This answered my exact question. Thanks again for the quick reply.

Comment: It would be appropriate then if you mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to stack exchange didn't know this feature. I will do it.